# Rounded corner listview items Background issue in android 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a listview code given below

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
        </ListView>
```

and here is the listview items layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_bg" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgRealstatePhoto"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgRealstatePhoto"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRealstateAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#7D7D7D"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRealstateHomeTypeBroker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="Loading...."
                android:textColor="#867C7D"
                android:textScaleX="1.025"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRealstatePrice"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:textColor="#006B9E"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRealStateStatus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/real_estate_text_bg_pending"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgRealstatePhoto"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ellectedofficialsoverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/expand_ico" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note: android:background="@drawable/listview_bg" in my relative layout**

here is the code of listview_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<corners android:radius="12dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#6DD8F9" />

</shape>
```

output on android 4.0 Qmobile All noir

[image]

Look the whole background of listview items became black.

while in Andorid 4.4.2 nexus 7 device and emulator I m getting the desired out come i.e

[image]

I want the layout in 2nd image in all devices. How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your listview_bg.xml this:

```
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: this worked. but Why I was getting the desired result in android 4.4.2?

Comment: Different version of Android, different settings... That was probably background color because you didn't set background color in code.

Comment: Thanks This worked. But setting android:color="@android:color/white" will affect the listview click highlighter. Hence I have Used android:color="@android:color/transparent". this work very perfect. Please update your answer regarding this comment

Answer (score 2):

You can try it by using andorid "CardView".By Using cardview u can manage easily rounded corner .Please check this [Link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/).Which can help to you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This Code :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ed4d44"/>

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have different color on different device because each device have there own default theme thus giving that result.

Solution is to give background color to the relative layout so it is not transparent

Add this in your listview_bg.xml

```
<solid
        android:color="color" />
```

Adding solid to you shape xml will fill your shape with your desire color

Answer (score 1):

Use the below drawable to get the desired output,as you are missing solid color in the background of  list itemsi.e why you are not getting desired output

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

   <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#6DD8F9" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" /> 
    <corners android:radius="8dp" /> 
</shape>
```